# WHMCS Custom product field on Product profile page

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs

I have looked all over and can't find it in the documentation through developer nor normal documentation, is there somehow or somewhere to allow displaying of all custom fields or X custom fields on a product overview page for the customer?

For instance we sell some products that have special keys in the custom product field for that product, we have added these custom fields to the product once the purchase is done. But how, other than the original email sent to the customer, do I show this to the customer when they view their product details page?

I figure it must be in the template file for product details but I don't know if there is a switch I'm missing to just turn it on or if I have to manually grab it (if it's even there to grab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just uncheck the `admin only` check then.
It will be displayed within the client area-> products and services -> product details.
And make sure that `clientareaproductdetails.tpl` contains something like following :

```
{foreach from=$customfields item=customfield}
     {$customfield.name} : {$customfield.value}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Question - can these fields be exposed to the client as editable inputs? It'd be nice for the client to edit some values related to their product.

Comment: for sure, you can allow clients to edit these fields. All you need is to modify your smarty template file and using html input fields within form data.

Answer (score -1):

Well , if you want your product custom fields to be viewed by the customers,
all you have to do is allow that custom field on admin panel to be displayed.

You can do that, by admin panel ->setup->product & services -> related product->custom fields

There you make sure that followings are checked :

```
Show on Order Form
Show on Invoice
```

And the following is unchecked :

```
Admin Only
```

Comment: No, that doesn't answer the question, the question wasn't to display on the order form for them to edit nor display on the invoice. The question was to display on profile page when viewing product details.